# How to use pregmatch to validate no characters /.%\@? in input fields and only A-Za-z0-9./ in another input field

Tags: php, regex, html

PHP validation preg_matches not working

For metacharacters, I know they are tricky, if they are within bracket [ ], I thought they become the literal values instead of wildcard and you don't need to escape with a backlash.

For $err_useridpmatch, I don't understand why when I input valid input, the error still show while for $err_passpmatch, when I deliberately input error string including ?, there was no validation error message.

```
<?php


if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && (!empty($_POST['submit']))):

    $userid = trim($_REQUEST['userid']);
    $password = trim($_REQUEST['password']);
    $err_useridpmatch = '';
    $err_passpmatch = '';

    if ( !(preg_match('/[^\/.%\\@?]/', $userid)) ) :
        $err_useridpmatch = '<div class="error">User id should not have the following characters:/.%\@?</div>';
    endif; // pattern doesn't match

    if ( !(preg_match('/[A-Za-z0-9.\/]/', $password)) ) :
        $err_passpmatch = '<div class="error">Password must only consist of lower or uppercase letters, numbers, full stop or forward slash</div>';
    endif; // pattern doesn't match


endif; //form submitted

?>
______________________________________________________________________________
HTML section:

<div id="form-content"> 


<form name="orderForm" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" class=""method="post" autocomplete="on">

    <table id="formtable">

    <tbody>
        <br>
        <br>
        <b><p> Please enter your user id, password and click submit</p></b>

        <br>
        <tr>
          <td class="label"><label for="userid">User ID: </label></td>
          <td class="form-input"><input type="text" id="userid" name="userid" value="<?php echo h(@$values['userid']) ?>"/></td>
          <td>
          <?php if (isset($err_useridpmatch)) { echo $err_useridpmatch; } ?></td>

        </tr>
        <br>
        <tr>
          <td class="label"><label for="password">Password: </label></td>
          <td class="form-input"><input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="<?php echo h(@$values['password']) ?>"/></td>
          <td>
          <?php if (isset($err_passwordpmatch)) { echo $err_passwordpmatch; } ?></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>    
    </table>

        <p class="required" id="required">Required fields are marked with an asterisk (<abbr class="req" title="required">*</abbr>).</p>



       <table id="tablebutton">
            <tr>
                <td class="buttonfunction"><input type="button" onclick="window.close()" id="cancel"  name="cancel"  value="Cancel"/></td>
                <td class="buttonfunction"><input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
            </tr>


    <!--          <td class="buttonfunction"><input type="submit" onclick="RegisterValidation()" value="Submit">-->


        </table>


</form>
</div><!--end form content section-->

<pre>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        print_r($_POST);
    }
?>        
</pre>
```

(1) User id should not have the following characters   /.%@?
(2) Password must only consist of lower or uppercase letters, numbers, full stop or forward slash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user ID regex that should validate a string that can't contain `/`, `.`, `%`, `\`, `@` and `?` will be

```
if ( !(preg_match('/^[^\/.%\\\\@?]*$/', $userid)) )
```

See the [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E%5B%5E%5C%2F.%25%5C%5C%5C%5C%40%3F%5D*%24):

[image]

The password regex that must only consist of lower- or uppercase letters, numbers, full stops or forward slashes is much simpler:

```
if ( !(preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9.\/]*$/', $password)) )
```

See this [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E%5BA-Za-z0-9.%5C%2F%5D*%24):

[image]

**Details**

- To include a backslash in a regular PHP regex string literal you need to double each of the two backslashes used to match a backslash, `'\\\\'`
- `^` matches start of string when not after an unescaped `[`
- `$` matches the end of the string if outside of a character class
- `*` is a quantifier matching 0 or more repetitions of the preceding pattern part (`abc*` matches `ab`, `abc`, `abcc`, `abccccc`, etc.). Use `+` to match 1 or more repetitions.

Comment: Thank you so much Wiktor. You're a legend. I found error in my php statement <?php if (isset($err_passwordpmatch)) { echo $err_passwordpmatch; } ?> where the variable is not the same name as passpmatch above. Fix them all work now! Thx.